# is asus Q87T motherboard compatible with Redhad Linux?

Tags: linux, centos, fedora, hardware-compatibility, asus

is ASUS Q87T motherboard compatible with RedHat Linux ??

I can't get answer both the two links below:

http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Q87T/specifications/
http://www.asus.com/websites/global/aboutASUS/OS/Linux1406.pdf

does anyone know it
i want to use "ASUS Q87T" motherboard for install "CentOS 7" or "Fedora 20"
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Neither CentOS nor Fedora are "RedHat Linux". There isn't really any such thing; there is *Red Hat Enterprise Linux*, which replaced the previous *Red Hat Linux*. Fedora and CentOS are both Red-Hat sponsored projects but are not Red Hat products.

Generally, Fedora is compatible with whatever is supported by the upstream kernel. Fedora does have kernel engineers, but they work very hard to *only* operate in that manner. Red Hat does things differently for RHEL, and those changes trickle down to CentOS eventually (although Red Hat *certifies* hardware for RHEL, and does not for CentOS).

In most cases, motherboards are nothing to worry about, although occasionally a newer model will need some kernel updates. The way to check is to search for various components like "I217LM lan controller" or "Realtek 8111G" to see what kernels they are supported in. As a general rule of thumb, if the chipset and components predate a Fedora release by at least six months, it'd be very surprising for it to not work.

In this particular case, I noticed that [openbenchmarking.org](http://openbenchmarking.org) has [result running Fedora 19 on this motherboard](http://openbenchmarking.org/result/1312163-SO-1312048SO44), so I'm quite confident in saying that F20 should be fine too.

(Disclaimer: I work for Red Hat on Fedora.)